# Como evitar animação de elementos que não vão caber na largura da tela?

Tags: jquery, animação

Criei uma animação em jQuery para o postal de natal de um cliente. Contudo, em ecrãs de resoluções tipo 1024x768 ou 800x600, aparecem elementos em locais estranhos:

[image: Bolas animadas]

O código em baixo esconde as bolas ao arranque, depois vai fazendo aparecer uma a uma até não encontrar mais:

```js
// prepare balls
$('#balls img').each(function(){
    $(this).css({
        "opacity" :  0,
        "top"     : "-" + $(this).height() + "px"
    });
});

// animate balls
function gimeBalls(){

    $("#balls img:not('.done'):first").animate({
        "opacity" : 1,
        "top"     : 0
    }, 400, function() {
        $(this).addClass("done");
    });
}

setInterval(gimeBalls, 400);
```

**Problema**

Como as imagens estão todas flutuadas à esquerda, se a última imagem não for alta o suficiente para ocupar a altura toda do contentor, a imagem que vem a seguir vai ficar como a captura de tela apresentada em cima.

## Pergunta

Como posso com jQuery detectar que o elemento a ser apresentado de seguida já não vai caber na largura do ecrã, parando assim a animação para todos os restantes elementos?

Ver [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/BzuR2/) com exemplo completo e a funcionar.

<sup>**Nota:** Se não for visível o "bug", basta esticar ou encolher a largura do quadrado de preview até se notar. Como as imagens estão na minha dropbox, o primeiro acesso ao Fiddle é "estranho" até as imagens terem sido descarregadas.</sup>

---

<sup>***Solução já conhecida***</sup>

<sup>A solução que pode resolver isto, é colocar todas as bolas em png com a altura do contentor onde estão a ser apresentadas, assim acabam-se os espaços que causam este problema. Contudo, isto trás mais carga de download para quem vê a animação, pelo que gostava de evitar esta solução. Por outro lado, respondendo à pergunta em cima, consegue-se evitar animar elementos que nem sequer estão visíveis.</sup>

Comment: "isto trás mais carga de download" a própria compressão do JPG/PNG não torna esse problema insignificante? Afinal, é uma grande área retangular onde todo pixel é transparente... Testei com `bola_pequena_verde.png` e o tamanho do arquivo mudou menos de 10% mesmo após ampliar em 100 vezes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basta modificar o CSS removendo `float` e alinhando verticalmente ao topo, exemplo atualizado: http://jsfiddle.net/BzuR2/1/

```css
#balls > img {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left:28px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Aqui fica uma sugestão:

```js
var wrapperWidth = $('#balls').width();
$('#balls img').each(function(){
    $(this).css({
        "top"     : "-" + $(this).height() + "px",
        "left"    : Math.floor(Math.random() * wrapperWidth) + "px"
    });
});
```

CSS:

```css
#balls > img {
    margin-left:28px;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
/* removi  float:left; */
}
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/5RkmU/1)

O que eu mudei:

- removí o opacity: 0; no jQuery, melhor usar no CSS para as bolas estarem escondidas desde o inicio (o jQuery pode demorar a correr e assim evita-se que as bolas apareçam subitamente)
- adicionei um posicionamento aleatório das bolas com `Math.floor(Math.random() * wrapperWidth) + "px"`
- adicionei um `position: absolute;` para o animate:top funcionar.

Comment: Esta muito interessante, só corre mal com a posição esquerda em aleatório porque muitas bolas tendem a aparecer praticamente no mesmo sitio! +1

Comment: @Zuul, fiz uma alteração para espalhar as bolas melhor. A minha resposta é a unica que usa a animação das bolas a cair. Se não queres essa animação então porque tens ` "top": "-" + $(this).height() + "px",` para fazer um animate a `0` ?

Comment: Perspicaz, reparaste nesse pequeno detalhe ;) Sim, essa definição de CSS não faz grande sentido para o problema em mãos, mas faz parte do seguimento da animação que as bolas levam... no trabalho final, se estiveres mais que 1 minuto com o postal aberto, as bolas começam a abanar (cima/baixo) uns pequenos pixeis.

Comment: ...Já deixei o meu voto a favor aqui, mas gostava de pegar nessa tua ideia e explorar a mesma um pouco mais colocando uma pergunta para se resolver a questão das bolas a animarem por cima de bolas já existentes, posso? E posso também contar com a tua resposta nessa nova pergunta?

Comment: @Zuul, sim claro.